# How can I use the built-in VBA editor on a high resolution screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, high-dpi

As you can see in the below screenshot, intellisense often doesn't leave enough room for the full description on enum members (and in some other places).

[image: Intellisense won't fit]

But I think `Dim`... seems fine

[image: Dim variable does fit]

I don't seem to remember this being a problem before I upgraded my computer (was 1366x768 now 3840x2160), so I'm wondering if there's any way of running Excel/Office/the VB IDE to get things to display sensibly? Or maybe this is normal and I've just forgotten:)

Specs:

- Excel Office 365 v16.0.11(...)
- Windows 10 Home

Comment: I don't think it's in relation with the resolution.

Comment: Tools > Options > Editor Format. Drop the font-size down to 10.